# SQL Server 2008 R2 remote connection error

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2, connection

I am getting an error while trying to connect to SQL Server with public IP.

I tried many things Adding port 1433in firewall but still it is showing the below error.

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to XXX.xxx.xx.xx ,1433.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10061)
>
> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008R2 there is no surface area configuration.

Comment: I did that all but still facing the same error.

Comment: Please post your connection string in `web.config` if your application is website.

Comment: Are you enabled TCP/IP  optional? Or your SQL services is running?

Comment: basically i want to access the SQL server remotely, If i am typing local ip/SQLExpress it is accepting and running, but i am adding Public IP/SQLEXpress or Public IP, 1433 it is not opening and showing above error. I want to access SQL Server from my window application from anywhere around the world thats why i am using Public IP. and port 1433

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10061)

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: Are you own target machine?

Comment: yes i owner it..

Comment: Hiee @vanlocare you there?

Comment: hiee @vanloc are you there?

Comment: I tried all to help you. You should see my link was post again or remove your SQL server.

Comment: @varloc i am posting again with pictures please check the error.I will be pleased if you can help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43290311/sql-server-public-ip-connectivity-error             @varloc please check